# Regex match for Case Insenstive URLS

Tags: c#, regex

I wrote a regex for URL match and it is not working for upper case, may i know how to fix it.

```
^(http|https)://www\.mywebsite\.com/test.aspx

https://www.mywebsite.com/test.aspx
```

When i do upper case it won't work

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/TEST.aspx
```

is there anyway to make it case insenstive

Thanks.

Comment: `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` ?

Comment: `(?i)^(http|https)://www\.mywebsite\.com/test.aspx`, using inline options

Comment: try here, its not matching http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=94760

Comment: (?i) is an option for .net.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/yd1hzczs(v=VS.110,d=hv.2).aspx

Comment: what is the generic way of doing?

Comment: depends on the technology you use, but usually is like `[START_MARK]regular expression[CLOSE_MARK] options`. something like `#^(http|https)://www\.mywebsite\.com/test.aspx# i`

Comment: in regexpal.com the marks are already added by system ('\'), the same with options (`g`)

Comment: yeah i just saw that /ig, works

Answer (score 2):

> may i know how to fix it.

Use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`.
Your regex wasn't escaping the last dot (`\.aspx`), you also can replace `(http|https)` for `https?`, i.e.:

```
try {
    if (Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, @"^https?://www\.mywebsite\.com/test\.aspx", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) {
        // Successful match
    } else {
        // Match attempt failed
    } 
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Comment: This is not in dotnet, this is one of the tools, so let me check how to do there.